# Pinch zoom not working properly in HorizontalScrollView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-canvas

I am arranging my views inside HorizontalScrollView and my each view(DrawView.java) contains rectangle. When the activity only contain this view, pinch zoom functionality is working fine(See Code 1 and respective image 1) but when I am arranging multiple of these views in HorizontalScrollView, it's not working properly because touch events of this view are messing up with touch events of HorizontalScrollView(Code 2 and Image 2).

Someone please help me to fix this bug.

This is a code for activity in which pinch zoom is working fine.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;


    public class DrawView extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        public int recog=-1;   // this variable will tell if onDraw is called for first time or is called by listener usinf invalidate()
        boolean listener=false;

        int data[] = new int[] {200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200};

        private  float MIN_ZOOM = 0.1f;
        private  float MAX_ZOOM = 10f;

        private float mPosX;
        private float mPosY;


        boolean zoom=false;    
        private ScaleGestureDetector detector;
        float  width=200;

        private float mLastTouchX;
        private float mLastTouchY;


        private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
        private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;


        private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

     // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
     private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;



        public DrawView(Context context) {
            this(context, null);            
        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            canvas.save();
            if(listener ==true)
                mScaleFactor+=0.4;
            Log.e("Ronak","Listener"+listener);

            Log.e("Ronak","ScaleFactor"+mScaleFactor);
            canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, 1);
            canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 100.0f, paint);
            makeLinesinRange(0,100,300,100,200, 5, canvas,100);
            width=mScaleFactor*300; 
            canvas.restore();
            requestLayout();

           }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

            final int action = ev.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    invalidate();
                }

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                  int heightMeasureSpec) {
               // int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                //int height = (int)(width * 0.5f);
                setMeasuredDimension((int)width, 350);
              }


        private void makeLinesinRange(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int size, int divisions, Canvas canvas,int width)
        {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
            paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            float kk=(x2-x1)/(divisions-1);
            for(int i=0;i<divisions;i++)
            {
                canvas.drawLine(x1+i*kk, y1, x1+i*kk, y2+size, paint);
            }
        }

        private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

                Log.e("Ronak","scale "+mScaleFactor);
                // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
                mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.3f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));


                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }



    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);




    }
}
```

DrawView.java. This is a code of single view. I am arranging multiple of these views in HorizontalScrollView

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    public int recog=-1;   // this variable will tell if onDraw is called for first time or is called by listener usinf invalidate()
    boolean listener=false;
    int view_number=0;

    int data[] = new int[] {200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200};
    int lines[] = new int[] {4,5,7,8,2,6,6,3,2,1,1,6};
    String[] type=new String[]{"Song","Music","Magazine","Audible","Videos","Apps","Other"};


    private static float MIN_ZOOM = 0.1f;
    private static float MAX_ZOOM = 10f;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;


    boolean zoom=false;    
    private ScaleGestureDetector detector;
    float  width=700;
    float height=500;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;


    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;


    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

 // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
 private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;



    public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);            
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.save();
        if(listener ==true)
            mScaleFactor+=0.4;
        Log.e("Ronak","Listener"+listener);

        Log.e("Ronak","ScaleFactor"+mScaleFactor);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, 1);
        canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 70.0f, paint);
        makeLinesinRange(0,70,300,70,200, lines[view_number], canvas,100);


        width=mScaleFactor*300; 
        height=mScaleFactor*100;
        /*int start=0;
        int temp=(int)width/lines[view_number];
        for(int i=0;i<lines[view_number];i++)
        {
            canvas.drawText(type[i], 50, 100, paint);
            start=temp;
            temp+=temp;
        }*/
        canvas.restore();
        requestLayout();

       }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

               // invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       /* switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mIsBeingDragged = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mLastX);
                float yDelta = Math.abs(y - mLastY);

                float yDeltaTotal = y - mStartY;
                if (yDelta > xDelta && Math.abs(yDeltaTotal) > mTouchSlop) {
                    mIsBeingDragged = true;
                    mStartY = y;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }*/
        Log.e("Ronak","Here");
        return false;
    }



    @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
              int heightMeasureSpec) {
           // int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            //int height = (int)(width * 0.5f);
            setMeasuredDimension((int)width, 350);
          }


    private void makeLinesinRange(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int size, int total_events, Canvas canvas,int width)
    {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        if(total_events<1)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(total_events==1)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(((x1+x2)/2), y1, (x1+x2)/2, y2+size, paint);

        }
        else if(total_events==2)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(((x1+x2)/3), y1, (x1+x2)/3, y2+size, paint);
            canvas.drawLine((2*(x1+x2)/3), y1, 2*(x1+x2)/3, y2+size, paint);


        }
        else
        {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        float kk=(x2-x1)/(total_events-1);
        for(int i=0;i<total_events;i++)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(x1+i*kk, y1, x1+i*kk, y2+size, paint);
        }
        }
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            Log.e("Ronak","scale "+mScaleFactor);
            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));


            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }



}
```

I also have a class which is extending HorizontalScrollView and is calling the above class(DrawView.java) for fitting multiple of these view in horizontal scrolling. Is there ant need to override the onTouch function of this class?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll leave this here: [How to take a screenshot](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-any-kindle-fire/)

Comment: Thanks.. I will keep this in mind next time. Can you help me in solving my problem?

Comment: @Ivan Bartsov
Can you help me in solving this problem of mine
Your inputs were very helpful last time.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054181/listview-animation-on-item-addition-not-working-properly

Comment: @user3265443 sorry mate, right now I've got a lot on my plate, I'll try to check out your question later

Comment: Thank you very much. Would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

First: **YIKES! Don't call requestLayout() from onDraw()** -- or you'll get 100% load, all it's ever going to do is relayout and redraw itself.

Second: Remove `onInterceptTouchEvent()` from `DrawView`. Since it extends `View` -- and `View`s don't have this method -- it'll not get called as part of the touch dispatch process anyway.

Third: which one's not working -- scrolling or scaling?

Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575355/scalegesturedetector-ontouchevent-always-returns-true), it's got some insights on how to handle multiple gesture-consuming components

Comment: Scaling is not working. However, when I pinch zoom in, sometimes its scaling up but not every time because its getting confused by dragging event of ScrollView. Also scaling down is not working for similar reason. Is there any need for overriding the onTouch method of HorizontalScrollView ?

Comment: What is the issue in calling requestLayout() from onDraw() as my parent layout of view is wrap_content.If not, then how do I change the size of layout